# Spring Transaction with JNDI and JPA transaction manager

Tags: spring, jpa-2.0

I have defined DataSource in Context.xml(JNDI) and i would like to use with JPA transaction manager in Spring application Context.xml. I don't want to use JTA Transaction since i am using tomcat server.

Could anyone help me how can i achieve this with an example? I am using @transactional annotations in DAO's and services.

Regards
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
         xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

  <!-- Provides access to the JNDI datasource -->
  <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/jpetstore"/> 

  <!-- Defines transaction manager -->
  <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Enables transactional behavior -->
  <tx:annotation-driven />

  <!-- other <bean/> definitions here -->

</beans>
```

Use `<jee:jndi-lookup/>` to get access to the `JNDI` data source. Then, pass the obtained datasource reference to an appropriate `PlatformTransactionManager` such as `DataSourceTransactionManager`.

Also, `<tx:annotation-driven />` should be provided for the `@Transactional` annotations to be activated.

To obtain a good understanding of Spring transaction management, I would recommend reading chapter 10 of Spring reference available [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html).

Comment: do not forget `tx:annotationDriven`

Comment: @Reza but i am facing the following issue org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'purpleDS': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context

Comment: @VijayM Sorry I am late; right after the answer I had gone to bed :-) I am quit sure the reason is either no JDNI datasource has been defined at all OR a wrong name has been used in the Spring config. Please double check this part and use the correct name: `jndi-name=""`

Comment: @Reza thanks for your reply!! i resolved the mentioned issue but now i am facing the following issues javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: CoreProject] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory,Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: unknown Oracle major version [11] I have clearly defined context.xml,peristence.xml(hibernate persistence provider),spring.xml(org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean,org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager) and Server.xml . I don't know what i am missing now.

Comment: This is most probably because of using wrong dialect for Hibernate. This must help you: http://maniezhilan.blogspot.com.au/2009/02/oracle-major-version-error.html

Comment: @Reza yes its got fixed now after adding the following tag in peristence.xml  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" /> I will post the complete solution in the same loop. Thanks for your fantastic help!!

Answer (score 0):

you can Define DataSource: Use JndiObjectFactoryBean class. To define the data source by providing JNDI binding name.

```
<!– Data Source JNDI –>
<bean id=”dataSource” class=”org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean”>
<property name=”jndiName”>
<value>jdbc/SampleDS</value>
</property>
</bean>
```